# how to display two separate notifications at same time?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, notificationmanager

My app needs to display notifications in the status bar whenever it is time to take some pills. If two pills are to be taken at the same time, then two notifications shall appear. Right now my app can display separate notifications if the pill times are different. The problem is if they are at the same time it only displays the one that was created (when I press a button) most recently. However it still vibrates twice. Any suggestions?

Info class:

```
    DatabaseHelper notiDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    notiDb.open();
    final String dataName = notiDb.getDataName(pushed_name);
    String dataDaily = notiDb.getDataDaily(pushed_name);
    final String dataWeekly = notiDb.getDataWeekly(pushed_name);
    String dataTwice = notiDb.getDataTwice(pushed_name);
    final String dataDosage = notiDb.getDataDosage(pushed_name);
    String dataStart = notiDb.getDataStart(pushed_name);
    String dataID = notiDb.getDataID(pushed_name);
    notiDb.close();

     ID = Integer.parseInt(dataID);
     int value_Weekly = Integer.parseInt(dataWeekly);
     int value_Daily = Integer.parseInt(dataDaily);
     int value_Twice = Integer.parseInt(dataTwice);
     int value_Start = Integer.parseInt(dataStart);

     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, value_Start);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
     calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
     int setTime = (value_Daily*value_Twice)/value_Weekly;



     Intent intent_noti = new Intent(this,Alarm.class);
     intent_noti.putExtra("ID", ID);
     intent_noti.setData(Uri.parse(intent_noti.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, ID, intent_noti, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), setTime, pendingIntent);
```

Alarm Class:

```
    DatabaseHelper notiDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    notiDb.open();
    final String dataName = notiDb.getDataName(pushed_name);
    String dataDaily = notiDb.getDataDaily(pushed_name);
    String dataWeekly = notiDb.getDataWeekly(pushed_name);
    String dataTwice = notiDb.getDataTwice(pushed_name);
    String dataDosage = notiDb.getDataDosage(pushed_name);
    String dataStart = notiDb.getDataStart(pushed_name);
    String dataID = notiDb.getDataID(pushed_name);
    notiDb.close();

    ID = Integer.parseInt(dataID);


   Intent intent_unique = new Intent(this, NotiScenario.class);
   intent_unique.putExtra("ID", ID);
   intent_unique.setData(Uri.parse(intent_unique.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
   PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, ID, intent_unique, 0);


    // Build notification
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("MedScan")
        .setContentText("3. You should take "+dataDosage +" pills of " +dataName)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.original)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
       .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
     //Hide the notification after its selected
   noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(ID, noti);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the id of the notification the same? If that's true I think that causes an override of the notification. Use different id's if you to show multiple notifications alongside each other.

Comment: No the Ids are unique. Ive checked to confirm they are different. for one of the pills its "1" while the other is "2"